# Android Studio shows password verification failed error

Tags: android, android-studio, github, passwords

When I try to load any project from GitHub and try to compile it on Android Studio (most newest version) I see same error message:

> Gradle 'PROJECT NAME' project refresh failed    Error: Password
>   verification failed

I tried to reinstall keystore file, delete and generate again gradles. No effect.
Also, it happens after some update. I can open old projects (both created by me and downloaded from GitHub).
Do anybody meet similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

What did you try on reinstall? If nothing working, simply create new `keystore`, and it surely gets solved. 
**Build>Generate Signed Bundle/APK> APK > Create new > ...**

And use this newly created `keystore`.